# Having trouble making a custom django view decorator (with args)

Tags: python, django, decorator, python-decorators

So I've read all the similar questions and copied what they wrote but I still keep having issues. So I want something like this

```
# Yes, I know django has one but I want to make my own
@rate_limit(seconds=10) 
myview(request, somearg, *args, **kwargs):
    # Return a response
...

def rate_limit(seconds=10):    
    def decorator(view):            
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # Do some stuff
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)       
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

When I run it I get the error

```
decorator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'somearg'
```

So I append decorator to take in args and kwargs and get this error

```
# New decorator signature
def decorator(view, *args, **kwargs)
```

and error

```
'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

**edit:**
So the solution was to use. Thanks **Martijn Pieters**!

```
@rate_limit()
```

instead of

```
@rate_limit
```

Comment: Hrm, none of these errors appear to make sense. You *do* want to use `functools.wraps()` to decorate the `wrapper()`: `from functools import wraps`, then `@wraps(view)` decorating `def wrapper(...)`.

Comment: Just change `def decorator(view):` to `def decorator(view, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: @karthikr: That is **not** the problem. It cannot be, because a decorator is passed *just* the function-to-decorate. I strongly suspect this is not the full code the OP ran.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This would address the problem `decorator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'somearg'`

Comment: @karthikr: that is addressing the wrong problem. I suspect the OP *did not call the decorator factory*. `@rate_limit` vs. `@rate_limit(10)`.

Comment: Also, you do not need 2 levels of nesting for the decorator. You can safely eliminate the outer `def decorator(view):`

Comment: @karthikr: **No you can not**. It is `rate_limit()` is a decorator *factory*. It produces the decorator. `decorator()` is the actual decorator here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first attempt works just fine, but you probably forgot to *call* the `rate_limit()` decorator factory.

In other words, your first error occurs if you do this:

```
@rate_limit
def myview(request, somearg, *args, **kwargs):
```

instead of:

```
@rate_limit(seconds=10)
def myview(request, somearg, *args, **kwargs):
```

You also really want to use [`functools.wraps()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) on decorators used in Django, especially if you want to mix this with other Django decorators such as `csrf_exempt`:

```
from functools import wraps

def rate_limit(seconds=10):
    def decorator(view):
        @wraps(view)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # Do some stuff
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

This ensures that any attributes set on the to-be-wrapped function are copied over correctly to the wrapper.

Comment: This did the trick! I mean, adding () to my decorator after adding args and kwargs to decorator. Why is it that I have to call it like @rate_limit() instead of @rate_limit like other decorators? Or are the parenthesis always required if it takes arguments?

Comment: @JaredJoke: `rate_limit()` is a decorator *factory*. It produces the actual decorator (it returns `decorator`) letting you build a different decorator based on the arguments. `rate_limit(10)` returns one decorator, `rate_limit(20)` returns another. Python then uses the `decorator` returned to actually decorate the `myview()` view function.

Comment: @JaredJoke: `@some_expression` really just means: execute `some_expression`, then take the result (which must be a callable), and call it with the function-to-decorate. So `rate_limit(10)` returns `decorator`, which is called passing in `myview`, and `decorator` in turn returns `wrapper()` to replace the `myview` function.

Comment: How does django manages to make both `@login_required` and `@login_required()` work?..

Comment: @DataGreed: by [varying behaviour](https://github.com/django/django/blob/39937de7e60052d3ffa9f07fdbb9262aced35d61/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L40-L52) based on wether or not you passed in a positional `function` argument or passed in other arguments.