# Creating a Decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm getting a value from a HTTP GET request. I'm checking whether the value is not equal to none. If it is , then return message is sent else further processing is happening.

```
def api_servers():
    installation_name = request.args.get('installation_name', '')
    if installation_name == '':
        data = {"description": "Installation Name is required"}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), status=400, mimetype='application/json')

    data = { "arms": arms_list }

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

Now, I want to check this condition using a decorator function. This is what I'm trying.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(): # I dont know what to pass in the arguments. Installation_name? 
                 # Maybe? But then how do I pass Installation_name

        if installation_name == '':
            data = {"description": "Installation Name is required"}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), status=400, mimetype='application/json')

        else: 
            return func()
    return inner
```

How can I achieve this via decorator?

**EDIT**
While I was proceeding, I found that I need another decorator which checks `data` is `None` or not.It also checks whether `installation_name` is empty or not and then I need to "recycle" both the `installation_name` and `data`. I re-wrote your code again. But the values are being interchanged, ie `data` gets `installation_name` and vice-versa. Can you please have a look? Thanks

```
def with_description(fn):

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    # Precheck
        installation_name = 'inst1'
        if installation_name == '':
            return 1

        # If precheck passes
        return fn(installation_name, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner


def with_description1(fn):

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    # Precheck
        data = 'data1'
        if data == '':
            return 1

        # If precheck passes
        return fn(data, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner

@with_description
@with_description1
def api_servers1(installation_name,data):
    print installation_name,data



api_servers1()
```

Comment: What would `func` be? Can you please explain what would the flow be like with decorators?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble making a custom django view decorator (with args)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965036/having-trouble-making-a-custom-django-view-decorator-with-args)

Comment: @aIKid - `func` will the `api_servers`. So, the flow is like this. I GET the `installation_name`. I need to created the decorator which will check if the `installation_name` is `''` then return something else call the wrapped function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm, give this a try:

```
import functools

def with_description(fn):

    @functools.wraps(fn)  # This is not strictly necessary, just pulls info (docstrings, etc) from fn and pushes into the wrapper
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Precheck
        installation_name = request.args.get('installation_name', '')
        if installation_name == '':
            data = {"description": "Installation Name is required"}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), status=400, mimetype='application/json')

        # If precheck passes, call the actual function
        fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

With this you win that every function decorated actually gets called only when the precheck passes.

**EDIT**

If as commented, you want to recycle the installation name, you just have to pass it to the function call. One possibility would be the following:

```
fn(installation_name, *args, **kwargs)
```

And of course, the decorated function has to expect that argument.

Comment: Works well. Since I require the `installation_name` later in the function as well, is there any way that I could get the `installation_name` value in the `api_servers`  function from the decorator created? Because I dont want to GET the `installation_name` value again in the function, hence saving from repetitive code.

Comment: While I was proceeding, I found that I need another decorator which checks `data` is `None` or not.It also checks whether `installation_name` is empty or not and then I need to "recycle" both the `installation_name` and `data`. I re-wrote your code again. But the values are being interchanged. Can you please have a look? I've edited my question with what problem I'm facing. thanks

Comment: It is doable, but do you need it in two different decorators?

Comment: Yes. Because in some function I need to test with only one decorator , in some with other and in some with both the decorators.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I would just include the variables you want to recycle in the kwargs dictionary (`kwargs['installation_name'] = installation_name`), and just `fn(*args, **kwargs)`.